# Issues installing linux headers on Kali 3.18

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux

I've been trying to install [virtualbox](/questions/tagged/virtualbox) on [kali-linux](/questions/tagged/kali-linux). But I ran into a few problems when trying to install Linux headers.

Before installing anything I ran:

```
$ apt-get upgrade  
$ apt-get update  
$ apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then restarted my computer.

I then used:

```
$ apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

And got the following errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-amd64  
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.18.0-kali1-amd64'
```

I used apt-cache search to look for packages with 'linux-headers' in the name and got :

```
linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-all  -  All header files for Linux 3.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-all-amd64  -  All header files for Linux 3.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64 - Header files for Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64
linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-common - Common header files for Linux 3.18.0-kali3
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
```

I noticed that most of the packages have kali3, whereas I have kali1. First off, what does the difference in numbers mean?
And how would I got about installing the headers on my computer?

I've been looking through forums but could find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install one of these headers with the actual corresponding kernel:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.18.0-kali3-amd64
```

Now at startup, you should have the two kernels listed. Try the new one. If everything is alright, then uninstall the old one ("kali**1**") and compile whatever you like with the headers. :)

PS: are you sure you executed all the updates as root?

Comment: Hey, I did execute all the updates as root. I tried your suggestion, and was able to run both those commands without any problems.  However, when I try to run     $  apt-get remove linux-image-3.18.0-kali1-amd64, it says its trying to remove the currently installed Kernel. This seems a little sketchy, am I about to brick my system?

Comment: Reboot first and choose the other kernel THEN you can uninstall the first.

Comment: When I run 
$ grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
I can see 
"menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64'"

in the list. However, when I boot to grub the option is not available. 
I've also tried using:
$ grub-reboot "Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.18.0-kali3-amd64" 
$ update-grub
and then restarting.

How exactly do I boot to the new Kernel?

Comment: If it's in grub.cfg, it's present at boot. There is no other way, this is what grub is *reading* to provide the list. It can be the default kernel or there is a "Advance Ubuntu" (or so) menu entry...

Comment: If you try to uninstall the old kernel now, what does it say?

Comment: I checked under the Advanced Kali option and still only see "Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.18.0-kali1-amd64'" Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.18.0-kali1-amd64 (recovery mode)'" as my options. I also tried using $update-grub and $update-grub2 and then restarting my computer with no results.

Comment: So I figured out the problem. Turns out I had to run $ update-grub from my Ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 1):

This problem I also met several times recently, my solution is:

`vim /etc/apt/.sources.list
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
:wq
$ apt-get autoclean && apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Or you can try

`$ apt-cache search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`